# Big tooltip outside window

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I have a list in the left side of my page with a tooltip (on hover) for each element.
I show the tooltip on right of each element but the tooltip content is sometimes big (10-30 lignes). When I display the tooltip of last items of my list, **its bottom part is outside the browser**.

Is it possible to get the tooltip always in the window. For example, when the mouse in on the firsts elements of the list, I should get the top of the tooltip right of my mouse and when I hover the last element, I should get the bottom of the tooltip right of my mouse.

A solution in CSS would be perfect but JavaScript is possible.

Thanks

Actual CSS:

```
.menu-item .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: -50%;
    left: 110%;
    border: solid 1px #333;
}

.menu-item:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a cheap workaround, but when you position the tooltip for the top half of the list items, make the point of reference the top (`top: 0px`) and for the bottom half of the list items, use the bottom as a point of reference (`bottom: 0px`);

**CSS**

```
li[data-title]:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100px;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

li[data-title]:nth-child(1):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(2):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(3):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(4):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(5):after {
    top: 0px;
}

li[data-title]:nth-child(6):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(7):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(8):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(9):after,
li[data-title]:nth-child(10):after {
    bottom: 0px;
}

li[data-title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

li[data-title]:before {
    content: ' ';
     width: 0; 
     height: 0; 
     border-top: 10px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
     border-right:10px solid lightgreen; 
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -5px;
     left: 100%;
     opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

li[data-title]:hover:before {
     opacity: 1;
}

/* This is to get a long list of stuff */

li {
    position:absolute;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-aling: center;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
    top:0%;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
    top:10%;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
    top:20%;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
    top:30%;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
    top:40%;
}

li:nth-child(6) {
    top:50%;
}

li:nth-child(7) {
    top:60%;
}

li:nth-child(8) {
    top:70%;
}

li:nth-child(9) {
    top:80%;
}

li:nth-child(10) {
    top:90%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">One</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Two</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Three</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Four</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Five</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Six</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Seven</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Eight</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Nine</li>
    <li data-title="This is a tooltip text that will hopefully be long enough!">Ten</li>
</ul>
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3h1z1gnn/